# Determine which table a ListParagraph element appears in Word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am scanning through a word document that contains list elements inside and outside of tables. Once I find a list element I am exporting its hierarchy number and the text associated with it to Excel. My scan is based on the list elements and not the tables specifically.

In some cases the list element will appear in the first column of a table and the text associated with it will appear in any number of subsequent columns of that table.  In some of the tables there are merged cells so I need to determine the number of columns in the current row of the table.

I keep getting a Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method on the line `tCol = oLI.Range.Tables(1).Rows(oCurrentRow).Columns.Count` and I'm not sure why.

```
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.Visible = True
Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Add ' create a new workbook
With xlWB.Worksheets(1)
    For Each oList In ActiveDocument.Lists
        For Each oLI In oList.ListParagraphs
            .Cells(i, 1) = oLI.Range.ListFormat.ListString
            If oLI.Range.Information(wdWithInTable) = True Then
                '#DETERMINE WHICH TABLE TO LOOK IN
                oCurrentRow = oLI.Range.Cells(1).RowIndex
                    'Determine which Row in the Table to look in
                tCol = oLI.Range.Tables(1).Rows(oCurrentRow).Columns.Count
                    'Determine how many Columns the Table contains
                Debug.Print tCol
                For j = 2 To tCol
                    .Cells(i, j) = oLI.Range.Tables(1).Cell(oCurrentRow, j)
                Next j
            Else
                .Cells(i, 2) = oLI.Range.Text
            End If
            i = i + 1
        Next oLI
    Next oList
End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `Columns` of the `Row` object.  You can use

```
...Rows(oCurrentRow).Cells.Count
```

to get the number of cells in the row.  Or, even better, you could just loop through the Cells with a For Each and not bother counting them.

```
Sub LoopCells()

    Dim tbl As Table
    Dim tCell As Cell

    Set tbl = ThisDocument.Tables(1)

    For Each tCell In tbl.Rows(1).Cells
        Debug.Print tCell.Range.Text
    Next tCell

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, I figured out my silly mistake a little while ago but couldn't post it because I'm new to the Forum.

I could use the proposed method above, but it would still require additional functionality because as can be seen above, I'm using the counter to move right for each column in the table.

Thanks again though!